# Xcode errors when using phonegap

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

So im getting a 2 errors when im using phonegap to create a native ios app and im not really sure how to resolve them. Xcode and Objective-C are beyond my knowledge right now so I'm not sure what to do. They state that there are multiple build commands.

```
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/gcollins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hanna_Instruments_App-dcesxqrxziqltacadrozhxjujrgz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hanna-project.app/icon-72.png
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/gcollins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hanna_Instruments_App-dcesxqrxziqltacadrozhxjujrgz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hanna-project.app/Default-Portrait~ipad.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode tells you that you are trying to add into the bundle the same files two/multiple times.

Select your Xcode project file in "Project Navigator". Look for "Copy Bundle Resources" Build Phase, it will show all files included into your project. Delete the duplicate reference.